# Mips disassembler

Tags: disassemblers, mips

So, I am looking for disassembler code for MIPS commands, for example: if the program gets word of command like 3c1d8010, I want to get the name of the command and the registers, which it uses: lui sp,0x8010

examples: 
25080268       addiu t0,t0,616
40806800       mtc0  zero,$13

I know, that it is possible to write by myself, but maybe somebody has done it already.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I typed your title into Google, and while the first hit was a commercial product, the second one has the description "mips-dasm is a mips disassembler written in C. **It accepts lines of 32-bit numbers that it decodes into their MIPS32 instruction equivalent**, through stdin or input file.". On github, so free & with source.

Comment: There's also an option of using objdump, see [linux - How do I disassemble raw MIPS code? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916130/how-do-i-disassemble-raw-mips-code)

Answer (score 3):

Try [capstone](http://www.capstone-engine.org/).
They have a good [documentation](http://www.capstone-engine.org/documentation.html) with [samples](http://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_python.html) like the following:

```
 # test1.py
 from capstone import *

 CODE = b"\x55\x48\x8b\x05\xb8\x13\x00\x00"

 md = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64)
 for i in md.disasm(CODE, 0x1000):
     print("0x%x:\t%s\t%s" %(i.address, i.mnemonic, i.op_str))
```

Output sample:

```
$ python test1.py

0x1000: push    rbp
0x1001: mov rax, qword ptr [rip + 0x13b8]
```

According to the docs they support MIPS and of course they have code on [GitHub.](https://github.com/aquynh/capstone)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have quick access without installing anything, try [The online disassembler](https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/).

Answer (score 2):

you can try radare2

```
E:\R2>rasm2.exe -a mips -e -d -
25080268
addiu t0, t0, 0x268
40806800
mtc0 zero, t5, 0
```

use mips.gnu to get the output you queried

```
E:\R2>rasm2.exe -a mips.gnu -e -d -
25080268
addiu t0, t0, 616
40806800
mtc0 zero, $13
```

rasm2 -h should show the switches

```
-a = arch (use -L to list the numerous architectures it supports)
-e = to tell that the input is Big-Endian
-d = Disassemble 
-  = to provide input from Stdin
```